# spring data elastic search highlight text

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, spring-data, elasticsearch-highlight

I am using Spring Data Elastic Search for querying from elastic search DB.

I need to highlight and display the searched text in the search results.

I have my setting like below

```
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .matchQuery("title", "Damaged"))
        .withHighlightFields(new HighlightBuilder.Field("Damaged").preTags("<em>").postTags("</em>").fragmentSize(250))
        .build();

FacetedPage<Result> results = myRepository.search(searchQuery);
```

But the data that is returned as search results is not highlighted .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide highlighting with Spring data elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049764/how-to-provide-highlighting-with-spring-data-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below link - It works

[How to provide highlighting with Spring data elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049764/how-to-provide-highlighting-with-spring-data-elasticsearch)